# Breaking Array of Numbers to Pages Using Php and Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Okay, i have this Range of numbers generated from an api (Like about 600 in total).

I am able to loop them into an html element with php.
from the below code, once generated, it will take almost forever to load up all the numbers and my design will look messy at the end of the day.

```
<?php for ($i=1; $i < $post['number_of_slots']; $i++) { ?>
  <button"><span><?php echo $i; ?></span></button>            
<?php } ?>

Then pagination should look like this
< 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7>
```

So i want to create a Pagination Like navigation that will break the numbers into pagination, to show like 100 numbers per page.
If it can be achieved via js or Jquery to avoid page reloading on pressing the page numbers button.

Comment: You can use array-chunk https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php to split  `$post['number_of_slots']` by pagination

Comment: php will definitely want to reload each pages, but i don't want that

Comment: are you thinking of getting all data once at front end and then split into pagination(Where while switching into page will not load) or get data from db in chunk?

Comment: i want to get data directly from front end then split it to pagination

i know of array splice in jquery but i am not very good at it..

Comment: This `$post['number_of_slots']` has all your data? But you want only chunk from it and display according to pagination.

Comment: yes it does have the number of  number slots available. let say `$post['number_of_slots'] = 600` 

now i want the pagination for this 600 numbers in sequence of 100/page

Comment: Share API code and response sample data. I will modify the answer accordingly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237021/discussion-between-colorado-akpan-and-navnath-jadhav).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="btnContainer">
</div>
<div id="dataContainer">
</div>

<script>
    Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'chunk', {
      value: function(chunkSize) {
        var r = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i += chunkSize)
          r.push(this.slice(i, i + chunkSize));
        return r;
      }
    });
    
  $(document).ready(function(){
    document.getElementById("btnContainer").addEventListener("click", getData);
      var masterData;
      var numberOfSlots;
      $.get("apiendpoint", function(data, status){
        masterData = data;
        console.log(masterData);
        numberOfSlots = masterData['data'].contest.number_of_slots;
        var arr = Array.from(Array(+numberOfSlots).keys());
        const noOfSlotsInChunk = arr.chunk(100);
        createButtons(noOfSlotsInChunk);
     });
     
  });
  
    function getData(e){
        const pageFrom = e.target.dataset.pagefrom;
        const pageTo = e.target.dataset.pageto;
        console.log(pageFrom, pageTo);
    }
  
  function createButtons(chunk){
    const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for(let i=0; i<chunk.length;i++){
        const btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        const initalNum = chunk[i][0]+1;
        const lastNum = (chunk[i][chunk[i].length-1])+1;
        btn.textContent = initalNum + '-' + lastNum;
        btn.setAttribute("data-pagefrom", initalNum);
        btn.setAttribute("data-pageto", lastNum);
        fragment.appendChild(btn);
    }
    document.getElementById("btnContainer").appendChild(fragment);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Alot, 
but it returns the number value of the erray like (1245) in page [1]...

Now, i want to return a loop of elements using php for(loop).. then make each of the element to apear in a pagination... Like `<?php for($i = 0; $i < 1245; $i++){ echo '<button>'.$i.'</button>';} ?>`  then break the button to pages in a sequence of 100 per page

Comment: @ColoradoAkpan.. See updated code.. Just add original endpoint instead of `apiendpoint`